# How to set the gnome-terminal color scheme to "Solarized Dark" via commandline?

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, 17.04

In Ubuntu 17.04 the gnome-terminal uses 'colors from system theme'

[image]

I am looking for a bash/script way to modify this, I'd like to have gnome-terminal use the Solarized Theme.  That means, uncheck the 'use colors from system them' and pick Solarized Dark from the build-in schemes.

[image]

I'm able to list out the possible keys that can be get/set:

```
UUID=$(gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default | tr -d \')
gsettings list-keys org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/$UUID/
```

And here's the list I get, but I can't figure out which one of these to set to get Solarized Dark.

```
audible-bell
cursor-shape
scroll-on-keystroke
cursor-colors-set
cjk-utf8-ambiguous-width
default-size-rows
encoding
use-theme-colors
custom-command
visible-name
login-shell
exit-action
use-system-font
rewrap-on-resize
backspace-binding
foreground-color
bold-color-same-as-fg
background-transparency-percent
cursor-blink-mode
default-show-menubar
default-size-columns
background-color
palette
cursor-foreground-color
allow-bold
use-theme-transparency
highlight-foreground-color
font
delete-binding
scrollback-unlimited
use-transparent-background
cursor-background-color
highlight-background-color
scroll-on-output
scrollbar-policy
use-custom-command
bold-color
highlight-colors-set
scrollback-lines
word-char-exceptions
```

I tried setting this to true/false, but it has made no difference

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/$UUID/ use-theme-colors false
```

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on here, but deleting the default profile with `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/` and then opening GNOME Terminal caused the profile to be recreated, and this time `use-theme-colors` actually had an effect. (Changing the scheme after that changed the `background-color` and `foreground-color` keys.)

Comment: Useful Gnome docs: https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Terminal/FAQ#How_can_I_change_a_profile_setting_from_the_command_line.3F

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also I can't find that something like Solarized Dark in `gsettings` or `dconf`.

**Method1**:

But according to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/133920/172882) answer, we can find Solarized Dark *RGB* parameters, and set `gnome-terminal` colors to that parameters.

You can do this with `dconf-cli`:

```
sudo apt install dconf-cli
```

And then find your profile id with this command:

```
dconf list /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/
```

That can be something like this:

```
:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/
```

And set this values on gnome-terminal to make your desired theme.

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/<profile id>use-theme-colors "false"
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/<profile id>background-color "'rgb(0,43,54)'"
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/<profile id>foreground-color "'rgb(131,148,150)'"
```

For example:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/use-theme-colors "false"
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/background-color "'rgb(0,43,54)'"
dconf write /org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/foreground-color "'rgb(131,148,150)'"
```

---

**Method2**:

Also you can do this with `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/ use-theme-colors false    
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/ background-color 'rgb(0,43,54)'
gsettings set org.gnome.Terminal.Legacy.Profile:/org/gnome/terminal/legacy/profiles:/:b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9/ foreground-color 'rgb(131,148,150)'
```

That `b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9` is my profile id and you can find yours with this command:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.Terminal.ProfilesList default
```

Comment: Just an aside, the `b1dcc9dd-5262-4d8d-a863-c897e6d979b9` is also my profile ID; maybe it's the default or maybe you're using vagrant like me

Comment: Hey thanks - this worked for me, I see now I was missing a `:` in what I was originally trying.  My takeaway from this is that 'solarized' dark  can't be done directly instead it has to be done the way you've illustrated.

Comment: @Mendhak I'm glad I could help you

Comment: @AliRazmdideh, is there a command line to swap between profiles, instead of modifying the current one?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [Gogh](https://gogh-co.github.io/Gogh/). I gave a fuller description in an [answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/728204/8224).

```sh
bash -c  "$(wget -qO- https://git.io/vQgMr)"
```

This opens up a terminal prompt that allows you to select from 200+ themes and then adds the theme to your profile.